# I need help in SQL query to get a different view of table

Tags: sql, join, rows

I can a question of SQL doing the something like the following, I don't have much information about the table schema being used but only and image and a goal.

The table looks something like this:

```
ID |DEF | ATT | VALUE 
---|----|-----|----- 
1  | 10 |  9  | 1234  
1  | 10 | 10  | 00199  
1  | 10 | 11  | Eduardo 
2  | 10 |  9  | 1234  
2  | 10 | 10  | 00199 
2  | 10 | 11  | Eduardo
```

And this is achived by a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, DEF, ATT, VALUE 
               FROM table 
               WHERE DEF = 10 
               AND ID IN ( 
                 SELECT DISTINCT ID 
                 FROM table WHERE VALUE = '001' 
                        OR VALUE = 'Agu')) 
WHERE ATT IN (9, 10, 11)
```

How can I make this look like

```
ID | DEF |VALUE|VALUE1| VALUE2 
---|-----|-----|------|--------- 
 1 |  10 |1234 |00199 | Eduardo 
 2 |  10 |1234 |00199 | Eduardo
```

Or how is this called so I can find more information?

Comment: search for `PIVOT` depending on your rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the pivot function like this should give you the result you want

```
SELECT
ID,
DEF,
[9] AS Value1,
[10] AS Value2,
[11] AS Value3
FROM(SELECT
ID,
DEF,
ATT,
Value
From table) as Sourcetable
Pivot (Avg(Value) FOR ATT IN ([9],[10],[11])) AS PivotTable
```